# Mariadb - Getting "Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value" error even though there is no null values for the Field

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run replace query then I get "Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value"
The replace query has select query. so I ran the select query to find which row has the null value.. but all rows in result have proper Int values.

I can't change the column default value to null because that column is the primary key.

I have no idea from where should I start to find.. any ideas?

(I can't write the query here because of security issue.. sorry)

Comment: Create a test case which produces the behavior of interest.  There's no reason to show private information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. There was a trigger for the table. The trigger was inserting to another table and that table has the column with not null option which caused the error. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a test with a REPLACE that tries to produce your error.

The solution is to provide a value for the column that can't be NULL.

The assumption is that your table's primary key doesn't have [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/).

> ```
> create table test (
>  id int primary key, 
>  A int not null default 0, 
>  B int default 0, 
>  C int not null, 
>  D int
> );
>
> insert into test (ID, A, B, C, D) values
> (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), 
> (2, 20, null, 2000, 20000);
>
> select * from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  A |    B |    C |     D
> -: | -: | ---: | ---: | ----:
>  1 | 10 |  100 | 1000 | 10000
>  2 | 20 | null | 2000 | 20000
> ```

> ```
> -- replacing id=2, but without column C
> replace test (ID, A, B, D) values (2, 20, 200, 20000);
> ```
>
> ```
> Field 'C' doesn't have a default value
> ```

> ```
> -- replacing id=2, C included, but without the primary key
> replace test (A, B, C, D) values (20, 200, 2000, 20000);
> ```
>
> ```
> Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
> ```

> ```
> -- replacing id=2, C included, PK included
> replace test (ID, A, B, C, D) values (2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table test2 (
>  id2 int primary key, 
>  A2 int, 
>  B2 int, 
>  C2 int, 
>  D2 int
> );
> insert into test2 (ID2, A2, B2, C2, D2) values
> (1, 11, 101, 1001, 10001),
> (3, 30, 300, 3000, 30000);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- example UPSERT as an alternative for REPLACE
> -- Requires primary key or unique key
> insert into test (ID, A, B, C, D) 
> select ID2, A2, B2, C2, D2
> from test2 t2
> on duplicate key update
>   A = values(A)
> , B = values(B)
> , C = values(C)
> , D = values(D);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  A |   B |    C |     D
> -: | -: | --: | ---: | ----:
>  1 | 11 | 101 | 1001 | 10001
>  2 | 20 | 200 | 2000 | 20000
>  3 | 30 | 300 | 3000 | 30000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2e59d8cd1a6b019ca187f6656f018ba6)*